# Count based on group with filter

Tags: sql, filter, count, group-by

I have a query that displays 2 columns: "Device_ID" and "Status". Device_ID is the name of all computers and status contains either "reboot" or "success" as values. I would like a third column that would count how many "success" there are for that specific Device_ID.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tgt.Device_ID, tgt.Status, src.cnt
FROM [TableName] tgt
INNER JOIN 
(
Select Device_ID, count(CASE WHEN Status = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0END) cnt
from [TableName] 
GROUP BY Device_ID
) src
ON tgt.Device_ID= src.Device_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.Device_ID,A.Status,B.Count_of_Success_per_Device_ID
  FROM Yourtable A
INNER JOIN 
(    
SELECT Device_ID,
           SUM( CASE WHEN Status = 'Success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Count_of_Success_per_Device_ID
      FROM Yourtable
     GROUP BY Device_ID
) B
ON A.Device_ID = B.Device_ID ;
```